# How to stay up-to-date with all the software (local and web-based)

Tags: versions

How do you stay up-to-date when it comes to new software versions? Above all, I mean minor updates (new version for your Joomla-Installation, forum-software, FTP-Client, ...).

Versiontracker, RSS-Feeds, Newsletter... what else? Anyone wrote a script crawling websites for new versions or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. frequents their news section/blog/forum, or
2. by RSS, or
3. by following the person responsible/developer/evangelist on Twitter. :)

Answer (score 2):

Often your operating system will help you with these things, at least in (most distributions of) Linux. As soon as a piece of software is available as an installable package, and installed, your package management system will keep track of it and it will be possible to find out that a new version is available.

For instance, in [Gentoo Linux](http://www.gentoo.org/), you would do the following from the command line to get a list of possible package updates:

```
emerge --sync && emerge -p world
```

The first command makes sure you have an up-to-date list of available packages, the latter compares all your installed packages (your "world") to the list, and reports back with one line per installable package. These lines contain the version you have, and the version available, so you can decide if it's worth upgrading.

There are probably several other ways of doing it, this is just what I use.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, many installers handle this for you, for example the InstallShield update manager.  Personally, I disable most of these until I need the new functionality or something goes wrong.  Reason being that if my existing setup is working well, an update is more likely to break it and cause me pain than adding value.  I like to pull updates, I don't like them pushed on me, exception being virus scanner and essential security.